# thy_goal_defn and keywords in Isabelle/HOL

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to get a good understanding of how math is built up in Isabelle. For whatever reason, all the tutorial/manuals hide a lot of the implementation details of basic types such as how the natural numbers, integers, rationals, and reals are constructed. When looking the src/HOL directory and examining the .thy files, I've encountered code blocks such as:

```
keywords
  "print_quotmapsQ3" "print_quotientsQ3" "print_quotconsts" :: diag and
  "quotient_type" :: thy_goal_defn and "/" and
  "quotient_definition" :: thy_goal_defn
begin
```

in Quotient.thy. Here, keywords is being used so that later you can define a type as:

```
quotient_type rat = "int * int" / partial: "ratrel"
```

and other related definitions. I haven't been able to figure out how the "keywords" feature works. It's not particularly obvious from the code, and the only documentation I can find is in the Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual where the following is written:

"The keywords specification declares outer syntax (chapter 3) that is introduced in this theory later on (rare in end-user applications). Both minor keywords and major keywords of the Isar command lan- guage need to be specified, in order to make parsing of proof docu- ments work properly. Command keywords need to be classified ac- cording to their structural role in the formal text. Examples may be seen in Isabelle/HOL sources itself, such as keywords "typedef" :: thy_goal_defn or keywords "datatype" :: thy_defn for theory-level definitions with and without proof, respectively." (p. 91)

This raises the question what a theory-level definition, which I haven't been able to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Isabelle's surface language, Isar, is extensible in multiple dimensions. In particular, a significant chunk of the keywords you'd usually use in day-to-day formalizations are defined in userspace. This sets Isar apart from many other programming languages, where syntax is fixed.

Roughly speaking, a theory file in Isabelle consists of two parts:

1. The header, which can be parsed statically, i.e. without running any custom code.
2. The contents, where e.g. logical definitions (types, constants, ...) and proofs can be mode.

Parsing of the contents happens in two phases:

1. First, the command structure is being parsed. This can be done by looking at the table of all the keywords that exist (those are declared in the header). There are various different types of keywords (as the manual points out). Command keywords start a new atomic chunk in the theory. (Consequently, theory contents can be seen as a sequence of commands.)
2. Second, the commands themselves are parsed, by using custom parsing code specified by whoever declared the corresponding keyword. This will execute any action, e.g. actually defining a type in the theory when the keyword `typedef` is encountered.

Commands can be classified according to the context in which they can appear. Top-level commands may only appear – well – on the top-level of a theory. Other commands may be freely nested in local contexts. Yet other commands do not modify the theory, but only print diagnostic output (`diag`). Theory processing in Isabelle takes that into account when e.g. parallelizing execution of a theory.

The example you mentioned, `thy_goal_defn`, is a keyword that adds some definitions to the theory and also enters proof mode, because `quotient_type` requires some proofs about the wellformedness of the definition.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused as "quotient_type" is mentioned nowhere again in Quotient.thy. After giving a closer look to the .thy file, it seems all of the implementation details are hiding in the .ML files being called in Quotient.thy. I'm not familiar with ML, so these files are fairly hard to read for me, but it seems that when you write something like: 'quotient_type rat = "int * int" / partial: "ratrel"', this gets past to the ML files and they try to automatedly define and try to prove the basic properties of "rat" using the theory developed in Quotient.thy. Any comments about ML files?

Comment: Also is using ML files to introduce new keywords considered part of the end-user experience of a someone using Isabelle/HOL or is just part of the source? It seems like defining something like equivalence classes should be able to be done by the user, but how it's actually implemented makes it look more like a fundamental structure to Isabelle/HOL.

Comment: While defining new keywords is perfectly within "user space" of Isabelle, it's very uncommon for beginners to look past that facade. It's usually something only advanced users do to automate common tasks. In particular, as a _user_ of the quotient package it's unlikely that you'll have to look at the sources.